# How to get integer PID of process?

Tags: c++, windows, process

I'm curious - how can I get the PID of an executable by name, or a list of PIDs, in C++ on Windows? I've referred to this documentation:

[Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/taking-a-snapshot-and-viewing-processes)

When compiling and running this code, the process IDs are all in hexidecmial format. Is there a way to get the integer value of the PIDs instead?

For instance, is there a way to get the value:

```
10200
```

Instead of

```
0x000027D8
```

Do I have to actually convert the hexidecimcal value, or is there a way to extract the integer equivalent?

Comment: Note that an _executable_ itself does not have PID. PID is related to a _process_, that is a _running instance of an executable_ (program).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetProcessId function

> Retrieves the process identifier of the specified process.

Read more [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocessid)

Code example (note [DWORD definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/262627d8-3418-4627-9218-4ffe110850b2) A DWORD is a 32-bit unsigned **integer** ):

```
DWORD MyGetProcessId(LPCTSTR ProcessName) // non-conflicting function name
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pt;
    HANDLE hsnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    pt.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    if (Process32First(hsnap, &pt)) { // must call this first
        do {
            if (!lstrcmpi(pt.szExeFile, ProcessName)) {
                CloseHandle(hsnap);
                return pt.th32ProcessID;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(hsnap, &pt));
    }
    CloseHandle(hsnap); // close handle on failure
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD pid = MyGetProcessId(TEXT("calc.exe"));
    std::cout << pid;
    if (pid == 0) { printf("error 1"); getchar(); }//error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you could you provide an example that actually retrieves the integer equivalent I will accept this answer.

Comment: @MarcusWIlliam OK

Answer (score 0):

The PIDs themselves are already integers. The MSDN code is *outputting* the PIDs in hexadecimal format. Simply change `0x%08X` to `%u` in the following 2 lines to output the PIDs in decimal format instead:

```cpp
_tprintf( TEXT("\n Process ID = %u"), pe32.th32ProcessID );
...
_tprintf( TEXT("\n Parent process ID = %u"), pe32.th32ParentProcessID );
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of getting the PID by name?